# How to create a line that would follow the outline of the mesh?

Tags: mesh

I would like to create an interior line that would follow the outline of the front surface of my mesh, but I don't even know if it's possible (It's a complex shape).
I would like to have the yellow line, but on the surface of the front face (it's now a loop on the side). Is someone there able to help me?

[image]

Comment: You would usually select the front face of the mesh, hit 'I' for Inset and drag the mouse, but with a shape that complex you're going to get all sorts of problems with overlaps so it's going to end up looking very messy!

Comment: Yes, I tried this option but it didn’t work, I was looking for one more efficient, less destructive…

Comment: It depends on how far you want it to be inside the original outline. The only other thing I can think of is to select that face, Duplicate it and P to seperate it into a seperate object then scale it down and use it with Knife Project, but I suspect you'll have the same problem.

Comment: A quite big distance... 
I'll might have to do it "by hand", I just wanted to be sure there is no automatic tool that could make it for me ahah, thank you for your help !

Comment: The fact of using the scale and knife project is that it will fit on some parts but not on the others ones...

Comment: I guessed that might be the case. Can't help any further I'm afraid. :^(

Answer (score 2):

## Smart Inset Edge with Geometry Nodes

I have a workflow for making a clean inset with no overlapping geometry. It's a multi step process but for a complex shape it could be quicker and easier than drawing the inset by hand.

[image: inset extruded]

### Setup

Duplicate your object and delete all but the face you'd like to inset. This workflow requires you to start with 2D geometry so you'll need to isolate that complex front face.

[image: isolated complex shape]

### Smart Offset Edge with Geometry Nodes

[image: geometry node smart inset]

Add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier with the following nodes:

[image: inset node network]

Let me breakdown what this network does:

1. Create a high-density grid that is the same dimensions as the bounds of the complex face.
2. Get the proximity of each grid cell face to the edge of the complex shape and delete the faces that are inside of some threshold.
3. Isolate the outer edge by deleting all edges with 2 or greater neighboring faces.

We now have a stepped approximation of our inset.

[image: stepped inset approximation]

Here are the input settings to my *Geometry Nodes* modifier:

[image: inset geometry nodes settings]

### Smooth Modifier

We can use a *Smooth* modifier to make this edge a bit more friendly. Tweak the settings of the *Smooth* modifier until the steps go away.

[image: smooth inset loops]

### Extrude and Boolean

The inset is still part of a different object. We can "realize" the inset loops and use a *Boolean* modifier to get the inset to be part of your original geometry.

1. Apply the *Geometry Nodes* and *Smooth* modifiers.
2. Enter *Edit Mode* on the inset lines object
3. select the edge loops you wish to keep
4. invert the selection and delete
5. select the remaining loops and press `F` to fill them
6. press `E` to extrude the shapes up

[image: inset extruded]

You can now combine the shapes with a *Boolean* modifier to get the inset to be part of your original geometry.

[image: inset boolean]

Setting this up for a one time operation would be more time consuming than just approximating the inset "by hand," but if this is an operation you repeat often it might be worth it.